# Move all API functions outside of React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have a React Application where have all API functions are within a React component `LandingContainer.js`

```
export default class LandingContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.methods = this.methods.bind(this); 
        // etc for each function

    }

    login(e) {//etc implementation}
    createAccount(e) {}
    deleteCv(id) {}
    //etc
}
```

I want to move all these methods into a single file; its sole purpose is to store the functions and to be called from `LandingContainer.js`. The functions use events, state, localStorage, [`js-cookie`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie), little DOM manipulation and passed parameters such as id.

The file doesn't necessarily have to be a React component although I suspect it's not possible to handle state otherwise.

I have no idea how I'm going to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move all your functions to another file, and access them by import, and set the returned variable to the state. Here is an example:

myFunctions.js:

```
function login(args) {
    const value = "something"
    return value;
}

function register(args) {
    const value = "something"
    return value;
}

module.exports = {login, register}
```

and access those functions from your react component and set state from a random function that suits your needs.

```
import {login, register} from './myFunctions';

export default class LandingContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.methods = this.methods.bind(this); 
        // etc for each function

    }

    myFunction(args) {
        const loginValue = login(args);
        this.setState({login: loginValue})
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

@Achraf advice mostly worked.

I moved all the functions into `API.js` and imported them but instead of having them return values. I bound the functions to `LandingContainer.js` component.

Functionality from what I can tell is 100% the same including access to state, events and localStorage.

```js
import {login, createAccount, getCVs} from '../_services/API';

export default class LandingContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.getCVs = getCVs.bind(this);
        this.login = login.bind(this);
        this.createAccount = createAccount.bind(this);
        //etc
```